# Using app:elevation in code - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-elevation

I'm trying to set the elevation of a `AppBarLayout` via code. When I do `app:elevation` in the XML it works without a hitch, however when I do

```
appBarLayout.setElevation(0);
```

It doesn't work.

My assumption is its calling the equivalent of `android:elevation`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Increment the elevation to  some non-negetive,non zero value(>0).

Comment: This doesn't work, plus I don't want there to be a shadow

Comment: check if you set a solid color with a transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which api version you are using , but at least you must use Api v21 to set elevation. If you set elevation in pre lolipop you should get an error , but use it like that :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       appBarLayout.setElevation(0);
    }
```

If you use it on below v21 you get this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.setElevation
```

The result :
[image]